# Youtube API V3 quota limits per user

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My web application is a social network for videos from different users.
I know that the Youtube API v3 limits per day is 50M. My case is that I use one single account to upload all users videos to my channel and at this moment I am no reaching the 50M limit but I am reaching the limits per user (3000/sg/user).

-I don't know very well the Youtube API V3
-I can not use multiple accounts to upload videos
-Right now Google is not allowing increase the quota limits

Does this quota limit (3000/sg/user) mean that only one user
 can upload a video per second (1600 units per video)?

If a normal upload takes 5 min to finish, does this mean it costs me 1600 units
 the first upload second or take some more units during the full upload?

How can I resolve this issue?

I spent the whole day searching a solution...
Thanks